# How can I do this for my website?

Tags: html, css

I have a little design question. I would like to make my website to where it has a header with a line two both sides of it.

```
------------- Similar to this -----------------
```

I don't know how I should go about this, and I couldn't find any sites implementing it to be able to peek into their html/css.. how should I do this??? thank you

Comment: `<h1>--- Header ---</h1>`

Comment: Take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/)

Comment: probably should have included header in my search when I was searching for it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<div class="section-heading">
  <h1>Your Heading</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
  position: relative;
  top: -2.2em;
}
.section-heading h1{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ss5h/

Comment: You don't really need a container for the H1 tag or all that CSS, you can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRPnk/